# Append hours and minutes from Date - most efficient way

Tags: regex, r

**tl;dr** : How to transform "10/30/2015 09:00:00" into "0900" using `sub` ?

I have the following dataframe `df` (`dput` at the end of the question):

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   75 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "10/30/2015 09:00:00" "10/30/2015 09:01:00" "10/30/2015 09:02:00" "10/30/2015 09:03:00" ...
 $ V2: num  22443 22553 22578 22565 22574 ...
```

The column which interests me is the first one, string format like this :

```
df[1,1]
[1] "10/30/2015 09:00:00" # all the days are the same, the time are always different
```

The goal is to create a vector or to replace `df[,1]` by this :

```
[1] "0900" "0901" "0902" "0903" "0904" ... "1000" "1001" # character format
```

or (preferably) by this :

```
[1]  900  901  902  903  904 1000 1001 # numeric format
```

using the fastest way possible.

What I have right now is this :

```
temp<-sapply(strsplit(df[,1],' '), "[", 2)
final<-paste0(substr(temp,1,2),substr(temp,4,5))
```

which returns this :

```
final
[1] "0900" "0901" "0902"
```

but this solution is not very efficient. I looked at `sub` which allow me to do this :

```
temp2<-sub(".*\\s","",df[,1])
[1] "09:00:00" "09:01:00" "09:02:00"
```

and then I can use `paste0(substr(temp2,1,2),substr(temp2,4,5))`

but I would like to know if it is possible to **create a pattern** which allow me to use `sub` and returns directly the expected output without having to use the not so beautiful `paste0(substr())`. I wasn't able to create one which will append the hours and the minutes and removing the rest. I also tried to use `strftime(as.POSIXct(df[,1],format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), format="%H%M")` but it is way slower than my first solution.

Here is the `dput`:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("10/30/2015 09:00:00", "10/30/2015 09:01:00", 
"10/30/2015 09:02:00", "10/30/2015 09:03:00", "10/30/2015 09:04:00", 
"10/30/2015 09:05:00", "10/30/2015 09:06:00", "10/30/2015 09:07:00", 
"10/30/2015 09:08:00", "10/30/2015 09:09:00", "10/30/2015 09:10:00", 
"10/30/2015 09:11:00", "10/30/2015 09:12:00", "10/30/2015 09:13:00", 
"10/30/2015 09:14:00", "10/30/2015 09:15:00", "10/30/2015 09:16:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:17:01", "10/30/2015 09:18:01", "10/30/2015 09:19:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:20:01", "10/30/2015 09:21:01", "10/30/2015 09:22:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:23:01", "10/30/2015 09:24:01", "10/30/2015 09:25:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:26:01", "10/30/2015 09:27:01", "10/30/2015 09:28:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:29:01", "10/30/2015 09:30:01", "10/30/2015 09:31:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:32:01", "10/30/2015 09:33:01", "10/30/2015 09:34:01", 
"10/30/2015 09:35:07", "10/30/2015 09:36:07", "10/30/2015 09:37:07", 
"10/30/2015 09:38:07", "10/30/2015 09:39:07", "10/30/2015 09:40:07", 
"10/30/2015 09:41:07", "10/30/2015 09:42:07", "10/30/2015 09:43:07", 
"10/30/2015 09:44:07", "10/30/2015 09:45:07", "10/30/2015 09:46:07", 
"10/30/2015 09:47:07", "10/30/2015 09:48:07", "10/30/2015 09:49:07", 
"10/30/2015 09:50:07", "10/30/2015 09:51:07", "10/30/2015 09:52:07", 
"10/30/2015 09:53:07", "10/30/2015 09:54:08", "10/30/2015 09:55:08", 
"10/30/2015 09:56:08", "10/30/2015 09:57:08", "10/30/2015 09:58:08", 
"10/30/2015 09:59:08", "10/30/2015 10:00:08", "10/30/2015 10:01:08", 
"10/30/2015 10:02:08", "10/30/2015 10:03:08", "10/30/2015 10:04:08", 
"10/30/2015 10:05:09", "10/30/2015 10:06:09", "10/30/2015 10:07:09", 
"10/30/2015 10:08:09", "10/30/2015 10:09:09", "10/30/2015 10:10:09", 
"10/30/2015 10:11:09", "10/30/2015 10:12:09", "10/30/2015 10:13:09", 
"10/30/2015 10:14:10"), V2 = c(22442.6858524496, 22552.7748887668, 
22577.9648686789, 22564.8417742602, 22573.7958926466, 22561.6260074242, 
22578.4969273076, 22573.9368593738, 22560.5696621363, 22583.6351125504, 
22563.9244299535, 22541.3550854309, 22535.1792445106, 22538.7283516493, 
22541.9685357942, 22549.673693988, 22536.0848222147, 22544.616494178, 
22545.9428853405, 22537.299523422, 22540.5364098182, 22528.1021034889, 
22511.3116720369, 22506.3479483641, 22507.558168335, 22527.1208239657, 
22538.2049982901, 22541.7992712468, 22549.7770949926, 22528.0226154986, 
22530.5431405792, 22549.9493136773, 22552.9504121553, 22563.3834376963, 
22569.1331816863, 22563.530786576, 22548.534182103, 22557.2196783034, 
22558.8349158659, 22558.4231669129, 22560.8480363532, 22549.1149362013, 
22538.496220018, 22540.2035600505, 22552.7047151487, 22545.3585981628, 
22551.2236255021, 22545.3629088232, 22539.8878805106, 22555.054048293, 
22548.3256620096, 22546.9335769395, 22539.6190972632, 22533.8926489234, 
22533.6247376657, 22536.8700903098, 22541.8482702231, 22537.8380668048, 
22546.8597666549, 22524.5161580447, 22518.2836071664, 22517.0611422674, 
22528.2131886847, 22530.156289448, 22516.2954996312, 22520.3056133929, 
22509.8912888173, 22491.7907956155, 22488.6023084655, 22476.1342466018, 
22477.0124169306, 22472.3565080568, 22475.1373622179, 22467.2661513395, 
22474.9329072207)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try [`sub("^\\S+\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+).*$","\\1\\2", s)`](http://ideone.com/1EbtoG). Or a safer one: [`sub("^\\d+(?:/\\d+){2}\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+):\\d+$","\\1\\2", s)`](http://ideone.com/DQe4dQ)

Comment: That's perfect ! could you please explain a bit ?

Comment: If Pascal's solution is better, I will not post my answer.

Comment: Using `microbenchmark` `sub`appears to be faster and I like the fact that it is a `regex`solution. Could you please post it ?

Comment: Side note: the combination `format/strptime` is twice as fast as the combination `strftime/as.POSIXct`. But slower than `sub`.

Comment: @Pascal: I got that too which is strange because according to the doc 'strptime converts character vectors to class "POSIXlt"' so we could expect it to be slower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure all your input is of known format, you can use

```
sub("^\\S+\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+).*$","\\1\\2", s)
```

The `\\S+` subpattern matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters and `.*` matches 0 or more characters other than a newline (greedily, but it does not matter here since we match the rest of the line up to the end - I assume the input has no newline symbols).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1EbtoG)

If you only need to handle the strings that match `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format (beside other formats), use

```
sub("^\\d+(?:/\\d+){2}\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+):\\d+$","\\1\\2", s)
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:/\\d+){2}` - 2 occurrences (due to the limiting quantifier `{2}`) of a slash followed with 1 or more digits
- `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespace characters
- `(\\d+)` - (Group 1 that we'll backreference to with `\\1`) 1 or more digits
- `:` - literal colon
- `(\\d+) - (Group 1 that we'll backreference to with`\1`) 1 or more digits
- `:\\d+` - a colon followed by 1 or more digits (but we do not capture them as we need not keep them)
- `$` -  end of string

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DQe4dQ)

Basically, the technique is to match the whole string, capture (with *capturing groups* `(...)`) what we need to keep, and in the replacement pattern, use the backreferences (like `\\n` where *n* is the capture group index) to the captured substrings.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer. If you still have doubts or need more details on the patterns used, feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: that's really great but then why is `(?:/\\d+)`also in a capturing group if we don't use it after ?

Comment: No, `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing group*. It means we group symbols, as we need to match a *sequence of symbols*, but we do not want to store the substring matched in any buffer. See [*Non-Capturing Groups* at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 1):

If format is fixed then we could use substr:

```
as.numeric(
  paste0(substr(df$V1, 12, 13),
         substr(df$V1, 15, 16)))
```

Benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  substr={
    as.numeric(
      paste0(substr(df$V1, 12, 13),
             substr(df$V1, 15, 16)))
  },
  sub={
    as.numeric(sub("^\\d+(?:/\\d+){2}\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+):\\d+$",
                   "\\1\\2",
                   df$V1))
  },
  strsplit={
    temp <- sapply(strsplit(df[,1],' '), "[", 2)
    as.numeric(paste0(substr(temp,1,2),substr(temp,4,5)))
  },
  times=1000)

Unit: microseconds
     expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval cld
   substr  46.786  50.711  61.08613  52.220  54.031 6657.496  1000 a  
      sub 127.078 132.813 139.43847 135.831 141.264  251.136  1000  b 
 strsplit 143.679 151.829 162.15411 157.866 166.016  331.426  1000   c
```